# dtruss on linux

Tags: ubuntu

Is there anytool lik dtruss which can run on linux (ubuntu)?

http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dtruss.1m.html

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`dtruss` is the Mac implementation of the Linux/BSD utility [`strace`](http://linuxhelp.blogspot.com/2006/05/strace-very-powerful-troubleshooting.html).